# How to manage selfreflecting light in object

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, artifacts

I get these weird miscoloured rings in my object from it reflecting on itself.

I tried using the "is reflection ray" but am not sure if there is a way to turn off only ray reflecting on the object itself.

[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by miscoloured? Are you in Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: Hi! It is cycles. Eevee looks fine. I mean that it comes across as much more redish than expected. I tried fideling with diferent subdivisions and weighted normals but it keeps the reflection. Even if i shade it flat i can see the rings of red in the inner edges.

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/